# Where is my Window? (Windows XP)

Tags: windows, windows-xp

Is there some application or workarounds to identify a hidden window (or dialog) on Windows XP?

The situation is similar to the one where you can't access the main window of an Office application because of a hidden dialog somewhere that waits a selection or a "OK" press. You try to click on the main window, and it activates, but you cant' move it or do anything with it.

Using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> or opening the task manager and "switch to" does not help. 
I also tried to "split horizontally"/vertically" on any "activable" dialog or window, but nothing works.

With the TaskManager I could however reduce my "active-incactive" application and with split I could modify indirectly its size, so the application is responsive.

How can I find the blocking dialog and put it on top?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing for me which worked was to minimize all screens (using the Windows key + D) - then using your mouse, click each open application one at a time - the dialogue box belongs to the application and typically when you maximize the application, the dialogue moves to the front (and becomes visible and click-able).

Comment: tried, does not work...

Answer (score 0):

If the window is not actually hidden, but moved off screen or resized to 0 width and/or height, try pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>. That will open the window's system menu, allowing you to move it back on screen and/or resize it.

Comment: does not appear any menu... when pressing Alt+Apace, I tried..